# Two parameters with same VO type n constructor is dry breaking?

Tags: php, dry

hey i have a simple question. But i cant find an answer.

```
public function __construct(
    private GeographicCoordinates $coordinates,
    private GeographicCoordinates $target,
)
{
    $this->calculate();
}
```

or something like this

```
public function calculate(GeographicCoordinates $coordinates, GeographicCoordinates $targetCoordinates);
```

is one of these break DRY rule?

Comment: Does the class do anything else? Is there a reason why you need to store both objects in the instance or could you just have a static calculate method?

Comment: I used GeographicCoordinates because tihs is my VO, there is small validation for data and no, class with calculate method isn't do anything else. Just calculating